# Mailchimp API failing on SSL handshake

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, mailchimp

I am using the Python Mailchimp API wrapper and it suddenly stopped working on two different machines.

My call and stacktrace look like this:

```
>>> result = mailchimp_api.lists.member_info(list_id, [{'email': email}])


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/<user>/.envs/<myapp>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mailchimp.py", line 1789, in member_info
return self.master.call('lists/member-info', _params)
File "/home/<user>/.envs/<myapp>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mailchimp.py", line 354, in call
r = self.session.post('%s%s.json' % (self.root, url), data=params, headers={'content-type': 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'MailChimp-Python/2.0.9'})
File "/home/<user>/.envs/<myapp>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 511, in post
return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/home/<user>/.envs/<myapp>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/home/<user>/.envs/<myapp>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/<user>/.envs/<myapp>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)
```

I understand there is some SSL certificate issue, but not sure where, and why this just started happening on two independent machines.

Comment: If you're using an OpenSSL version older then 1.0.2 then I'd suspect the reason is the same as in [this](https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi/issues/26) issue, the certificate chain of api.mailchimp.com _does_ have a certificate crossigned by a 1024 bit root certificate.

Comment: So my openssl verion is `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`. Should that be upgraded?

Comment: If there is a newer version available for your distro, then yes, upgrade. If that's not possible, then you can try the workaround described [here](https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi/issues/26#issuecomment-138336586), e.g. by setting `export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE="$(python -c 'import certifi; print(certifi.old_where())')"`, but you should be aware that this may reduce security, read [this](https://lukasa.co.uk/2015/04/Certifi_State_Of_Union/) for more details.